# How to do Web scraping through R from url to csv with rvest

Tags: html, r, xml, web-scraping, rvest

```
library(rvest)

base_url <- "https://movie.naver.com/movie/sdb/rank/rmovie.nhn?sel=pnt&date=20220502"

webpage <- read_html(base_url)

movie_nodes <- webpage %>%
html_nodes(".tit5 \> a")

codes <- substr(movie_nodes, nchar(movie_nodes)-31, nchar(movie_nodes)-25)

codes_t <- gsub(""", "", codes)

tds <- codes_t %>%
  html_nodes("td") %>%
  html_text ()

movie_data <- data.frame(matrix(codes, ncol = 100, nrow = 32))

write.csv(movie_data, "Downloads/movie_data.csv")
```

The following link contains information that lists 100 movies in order of rating. Collect the #titles and codes of 100 movies using links.

```
https://movie.naver.com/movie/sdb/rank/rmovie.nhn?sel=pnt&date=20220502
```

Only changes the code at the end of the link to collect the details of all other movies.

```
https://movie.naver.com/movie/bi/mi/point.nhn?code=191613
```

In this way, we collected information from 32 items of 100 movies but I don’t know how to do #that. Sorry to write like to chase waterfalls.

I want to deposit data_set from the url and make a csv file but my codes are not activated.

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of how to achieve what you've asked for, assuming I've understood your question correctly. (Please note that I'm not familiar with Korean.)

It is often useful to break down tasks such as these into functions. In this case, the first function is designed to download a list of movies from your base_url, along with the corresponding "code" that can be used to infer each movie's unique URL. This function is then applied to two pages to obtain a list of 100 movies, as each page only displays 50 movies.

The second function is responsible for taking a movie's code as input and extracting information from its page. For this example, we only extract the ratings displayed at the top of the page. This function is then applied to each extracted `movie_code`. The resulting data frame is saved to a CSV file.

Here's the code:

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

## Function for getting the list of movies from the `base_url`.
retrieve_movie_list <- function(page, date = "20220502") {
  r <- GET(
    "https://movie.naver.com/movie/sdb/rank/rmovie.nhn",
    query = list(sel = "pnt", page = page, date = date)
  )
  raw <- content(r, type = "text/html", encoding = "UTF-8")

  raw %>%
    html_node(".list_ranking") %>%
    html_table() %>%
    select(2, 4) %>%
    filter(영화명 != "") %>%
    mutate(
      movie_code = raw %>%
        html_nodes(".tit5") %>%
        html_nodes("a") %>%
        html_attr("href") %>%
        gsub("^.*code=(\\d+)$", "\\1", .),
      date = date,
      rank = ((page - 1) * 50) + row_number() # assumes 50 movies per page
    )
}

## Get the movies from the first two pages (100 movies):
num_pages <- 2
movie_list <- map_dfr(
  seq_len(num_pages),
  \(page) retrieve_movie_list(page, date = "20220502")
)

## Function for getting some information from the page of each movie.
retrieve_movie_info <- function(movie_code) {
  r <- GET(
    "https://movie.naver.com/movie/bi/mi/basic.naver?",
    query = list(code = movie_code)
  )
  raw <- content(r, type = "text/html", encoding = "UTF-8")

  raw_scores <-
    raw %>%
    html_node(".main_score") %>%
    html_nodes("div.score")

  ## Here we just extract the scores at the top of the page; but you
  ## can put whatever parsing you want for here for extracting some
  ## thing from the page of the movie.
  tibble(
    name = map_chr(
      raw_scores, \(x)
        x %>%
          html_node("span > em") %>%
          html_text2() %>%
          gsub(" +", "_", .)),
    value = map_dbl(
      raw_scores, \(x) 
        x %>%
          html_node(".star_score") %>%
          html_nodes("em") %>%
          html_text() %>%
          paste0(collapse = "") %>%
          as.numeric())
  ) %>%
    filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
    spread(name, value)
}

movie_data <-
  movie_list %>%
  mutate(movie_info = map(movie_code, retrieve_movie_info)) %>%
  unnest(cols = c(movie_info))

## Let's look at what we got:
movie_data
> # A tibble: 100 × 8
>   영화명                 평점 movie…¹ date   rank 네티…² 관람객…³ 기자_…⁴
>   <chr>                 <dbl> <chr>   <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
> 1 클라우스               9.81 191613  2022…     1   9.65    NA      NA
> 2 그린 북                9.6  171539  2022…     2   9.6      9.55    7.29
> 3 가버나움               9.59 174830  2022…     3   9.6      9.54    7.33
> 4 밥정                   9.56 186114  2022…     4   9.6      9.7     7
> 5 장민호 드라마 최종회   9.55 213746  2022…     5   9.4      9.9    NA
> 6 디지몬 어드벤처 라스…  9.54 192613  2022…     6   9.51    NA      NA
> 7 베일리 어게인          9.53 144906  2022…     7   9.54     9.42    5.4
> 8 원더                   9.53 151196  2022…     8   9.53     9.43    6.86
> 9 아일라                 9.52 169240  2022…     9   9.52     9.13    5.25
> 10 극장판 바이올렛 에버…  9.51 196843  2022…    10   9.5      9.68    6.5
> # … with 90 more rows, and abbreviated variable names ¹​movie_code,
> #   ²​네티즌_평점, ³​관람객_평점, ⁴​`기자_·_평론가_평점`
> # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

## Write to file.
write.csv(movie_data, "Downloads/movie_data.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Then, is there any solution only to use rvest, without the another library?

Comment: It is possible but why, when this solves your problem? The wish to only use rest was not specified in your question

Comment: because the librarys makes error and trouble. I want to solve it by myself, but little bit complex and hard to modify it.
Thank you

Comment: Which library and what error do they give? (If they are simply missing, you can install them by running `install.packages(c("httr", "rvest", "dplyr", "tidyr", "purrr"))`)